# What does it mean to receive a 0xcccccccccccccccc pointer value from std::partition?

Tags: c++

I want to spatially partition some tree nodes, but I receive a `0xcccccccccccccccc` pointer value from [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) at a breakpoint while debugging. Does someone know what this means?

```
template <typename NodeData> struct PartitionPredicate {
    PartitionPredicate(float s, uint32_t a) : splitPos(s), splitAxis(a) {}
    float splitPos;
    uint32_t splitAxis;

    bool operator()(const NodeData *data) const {
        return data->p[splitAxis] <= splitPos;
    }
};

...
const NodeData **m = std::partition(&buildNodes[start], &buildNodes[end], PartitionPredicate<NodeData>(splitPos, splitAxis));
uint32_t mid = start + (m - &buildNodes[start]);
// buildNodes is of type const NodeData **
...
```

Values: `start=0`, `end=407838` (size of `buildNodes` vector)

```
m = 0xcccccccccccccccc
mid > 3000000000
```

I changed the type of `start`, `end` and `mid` to my `uint32_t` instead of `int` because I recieved a huge negative value for `mid`, but an acceptable value for `m`.

**Edit**: I placed the breakpoint too early. The returned pointer is not known yet and Visual Studio seems to precompute all nearby values based on their own default initialization.

`buildNodes` is located at 0x00000000050c0070
`m` is located at 0x0000000005161c58
so mid = 82616 -> ok

Comment: Can you show a reproducible code sample? Also, where did you put the breakpoint?

Comment: Is `buildNodes` fully populated with 407838 valid pointers?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis It seems that Visual Studio gives all variables values and even computes results beyond the breakpoint. The breakpoint was located on the partition line, so I guess the result was not yet returned.

Comment: @MikeSeymour and MichaelFoukarakis The pointers are all valid because I extend the build method of an existing and already working rendering framework. The framework uses the std::nth_element(&buildNodes[start], &buildNodes[splitPos],
                     &buildNodes[end], CompareNode<NodeData>(splitAxis)); method instead which correctly behaves.

Comment: why not use real iterators, since `buildNodes` is a vector?

Comment: @nishantjr the initialisation is done with a vector of the right size somewhere else, I have no idea why a vector is used instead of an array. The other methods work with const NodeData **. So if the parameter types are changed, you can indeed use the iterators of the vector class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`m` is not initialized - it has no valid value yet. The actual value of `0xcccccccccccccccc` is what system fills the memory with so that it is possible to detect uninitalized variables. This value is picked specifically so that it's "not a valid memory address" - that way, you can't accidentally or on purpose use the memory of an uninitialized variable without getting some sort of error or trap.

Comment: But std::partition has to return something? the default seems to be the &buildNodes[start]?

Comment: Yes it should return the iterator to the first element of the second group. See this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I wrongly assumed the breakpoint to be after the line initializing `m`, my bad. No UB in sight.